# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "sein aus" und "stammen aus"

Tags: meaning, verb

Das Möbelstück stammt aus dem 17. Jahrhundert.
Das Möbelstück ist aus dem 17. Jahrhundert.
Sind die beiden Formulierungen gleichwertig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, die beiden Sätze haben die gleiche Bedeutung.

Komplette Gleichwertigkeit gibt es bei verschiedenen Formulierungen ja kaum. Das Verb "ist" ist natürlich deutlich einfacher und hat eine deutlich breitere Bedeutung als "stammt", deshalb ist der Satz mit "stammt" vielleicht eine etwas höhere Sprachebene (Register) und wird vielleicht auch in anderen Kontexten benutzt. "Stammt" hat auch spezifischere Assoziationen, zum Beispiel mit *Ursprung* und *Anfang* und *dem Beginn eines langen Weges*.

Zu der breiteren Frage aus der Überschrift: Je nach Subjekt und Objekt kann es auch durchaus unterschiedliche Bedeutungen geben.

Wenn man z.B. über eine Person sagt:

> Sie ist aus München.

dann heißt das normalerweise (vor allem, wenn der Satz außerhalb von München fällt), dass sie dort wohnt.

Dagegen bezieht sich der Satz

> Sie stammt aus München.

fast immer auf der Ort der Geburt oder des frühen Aufwachsens.